# flask, lighttpd with fastcgi can't get it to work

Tags: python, lighttpd, fastcgi

i'm tring to deploy a simple flask script to a lighttpd server with fastcgi.

this is the configuration file for lighttpd builded using the flask documentation http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/fastcgi/#configuring-lighttpd

```
server.modules = ( 
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",
        "mod_fastcgi",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                                "index.htm", "default.htm",
                               " index.lighttpd.html" )

url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

var.home_dir = "/var/lib/lighttpd"
var.socket_dir = home_dir + "sockets/"
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl"

dir-listing.encoding        = "utf-8"
server.dir-listing          = "enable"

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/x-javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"


fastcgi.server = ("weibo/callback.fcgi" =>
    ((  
        "socket" => "/tmp/weibocrawler-fcgi.sock",
        "bin-path" => "/var/www/weibo/callback.fcgi",
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "max-procs" => 1
    ))  
)

url.rewrite-once = ( 
    "^(/weibo($|/.*))$" => "$1",
    "^(/.*)$" => "weibo/callback.fcgi$1"
```

and this is the script i'm tring to run:

```
#!/home/nrl/kuro/weiboenv/bin/python
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from callback import app 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(application, bindAddress='/tmp/weibocrawler-fcgi.sock').run()
```

but i have this error testing the configuration file i get this error:
2013-07-02 17:15:42: (configfile.c.912) source: lighttpd.conf.new line: 52 pos: 1 parser failed somehow near here: weibo/callback.fcgi$1

when i remove the urlrewrite i get these errors in the log even if the daemon start:

```
2013-07-02 16:25:53: (log.c.166) server started 
2013-07-02 16:25:53: (mod_fastcgi.c.1104) the fastcgi-backend fcgi.py failed to start: 
2013-07-02 16:25:53: (mod_fastcgi.c.1108) child exited with status 2 fcgi.py 
2013-07-02 16:25:53: (mod_fastcgi.c.1111) If you're trying to run your app as a FastCGI backend, make sure you're using the FastCGI-enabled version.
If this is PHP on Gentoo, add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags. 
2013-07-02 16:25:53: (mod_fastcgi.c.1399) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed. 
2013-07-02 16:25:53: (server.c.938) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.
```

Comment: where do you get `/tmp/weibocrawler-fcgi.sock` from ? or did you just manually typed in a path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the url.rewrite with a `)`.

That fcgi error seems to be referring to an fcgi script that I don't see mentioned in your configuration snippet. Is that the whole config? Is there anything in the conf.enabled directory?

Comment: this seem the right answer, i can now star correctly the server, i changed name to the application and then forgot to change it in one of the place where was named. i now get an error 500 but it's a separate issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you spawn the fcgi-app with lighttpd (bin-path option in the fastcgi.server block), the fcgi-app must not use the socket name (lighttpd will bind the socket to STDIN of the fcgi-app, and the fcgi-app usually detects this).